# According to the Rema/Tosfot, is it permissible to see a secular concert in a venue that serves alcoholic beverages?

Tags: halacha, music, performance-entertainment, tosfot, rama

[Halachipedia:](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Listening_to_Music)  Tosfot (Gittin 7a s.v. Zimra) understand that the prohibition includes only music at feasts of wine, as in the Mishna Sotah 48a.

Would a concert that serves alcoholic beverages (including wine) fall under this prohibition (according to the Rema/Tosfot)?